# AppiumFieldDecorator method is giving error with latest serenity version

Tags: java, appium, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am new to Serenity Appium. I am trying to achieve Serenity-Cucumber-Appium with page object mechanism. To achieve page object I came across below method need to have in a base Page object class.

```
public class MobilePageObject extends PageObject {
    public MobilePageObject(final WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver, new Predicate<PageObject>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(PageObject page) {
                PageFactory
                        .initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(((WebDriverFacade) page.getDriver()).getProxiedDriver(),
                                page.getImplicitWaitTimeout().in(TimeUnit.SECONDS), TimeUnit.SECONDS), page);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is working fine when I am using below version of Serenity and Cucumber.

```
<serenity.version>1.7.4</serenity.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.6.3</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>1.7.4</serenity.maven.version>
```

However, if I am using below versions :

```
<serenity.version>1.9.20</serenity.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.8</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>1.9.20</serenity.maven.version>
```

then it's giving me compile time error at `in` method as :

```
Cannot resolve method 'in(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
```

Can you please help me, how I can overcome this and use the page object mechanism effectively for Appium Serenity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I am able to resolve this issue. With the latest Serenity version need to modify the page object class as below :

```
public class MobilePageObject extends PageObject {

    public MobilePageObject(final WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver, new Predicate<PageObject>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(PageObject page) {
                PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(((WebDriverFacade) page.getDriver()).getProxiedDriver()), page);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also to get the proper Serenity reports use the command `mvn verify` command to execute the test.

Thanks for support!

Comment: Is there any way to run Selenium tests along with these appium tests using Serenity? Both tests together.

Comment: I haven't yet tried such. I need to work on that front